# C-Server - first 3 characters of a string

Tags: c

a test string comes in

```
 123-eee
```

name of it: "**inn**"

I want to print only first **3** characters of it.

all the action happens here:

```
strncpy(inn2, inn, 3);
printf(inn);
printf(inn2);
```

this actually works. it prints both **inn** and **inn2** but if I remove

```
printf(inn);
```

this wont do it's job:

```
printf(inn2);
```

What's the problem ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>

char outt[15];
char inn[100];
char inn2[100];

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 88;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);

    ssize_t bytesRead = read(client_fd,inn,sizeof(inn) - 1);
    if ( bytesRead > 0 )
    {
    inn[ bytesRead ] = '\0';
    strncpy(inn2, inn, 3);
    printf(inn);
    printf(inn2);
    }

    snprintf(outt, sizeof outt, "%s\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));


    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, outt, sizeof(outt) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the string be null terminated? strncpy does not null-terminate strings.

Comment: what is the output and expected output?

Comment: when this is alone: **printf(inn2);** there is no output at all.

Comment: In the future, you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also tried.. **printf("%.3s", inn);** it also ONLY WORKS IF.. i put **printf(inn);** above it or below it. otherwise it simply is silent alone.

Comment: Typical sign of *undefined behaviour* somewhere in the code. Like trying to whack bumps out of the carpet, they just move somewhere else.

Comment: use a debugger (gdb, windbg,...) or try to use `puts( )` first maybe this is one of the `printf()` issues...

Comment: Without a newline specifier in the format, there is no guarantee that anything will show up on stdout.

Comment: **puts (inn2);** seems to be working. so **printf** is a bad thing ?

Comment: @D0rt3r `printf(foo)` is a bad thing. Use `printf("%s", foo)` instead. It's a security hole as `foo` may contain `%n`.

Comment: **inn2[3] = '\0';
    printf("%s", inn2);** failed. perhaps it is a new line issue. as "Frenk" said.. there must be a lack of guarantee with linux when there is no **newline**

Comment: @D0rt3r Use `fflush` if you don't want to print `newline` character but force the write to output stream.

Comment: Ultimately the solution seems to be the newline. **printf("%s\n", inn2);** or to use "**puts ()**" which probably automatically adds new line. ( assuming )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the standard output stream is line buffered, so output will not show up until you print a newline character, or the buffer becomes full. Add a `printf("\n");` after your output statements and see if it works.

Comment: buffer flush! that was the main issue after all :)

Answer (score 2):

You can print just the first 3 characters of the string with

```
printf("%.3s", inn);
```

Provided the string has at least 3 characters it need not be a proper nul terminated string.

Comment: something strange is going on with my app. your code also only works if I place **printf(inn);** above or below it. otherwise there is no output.

Comment: Aside: *never* pass a string directly to `printf` family of functions - especially one supplied from an external source or from the user. You make the code open to abuse, or accident, if the string should contain a format specifier. Always pass the string as an argument for `%s` format.

Answer (score 1):

1. `strncpy(inn2, inn, 3);`

If there is no null byte among the first `3` bytes of `inn`, the string placed in `inn2` will not be null-terminated. So `strncpy(inn2, inn, 3);` should be followed by `inn2[3] = '\0'`

2. `printf(foo);`

Such code often indicates a bug, since `foo` may contain  a  `%`  character.   If  `foo`  comes  from untrusted  user  input, it may contain `%n`, causing the `printf()` call to write to memory and creating a security hole. Use `printf("%s", foo);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`inn2` has to be *null-terminated* for `printf()` ?

Comment: added **inn2[3] = '\0';** below **strncpy(inn2, inn, 3);** still no output unless there is also **printf(inn);** above **printf(inn2);**

Comment: what happens if you try `puts (inn2);` or `printf("%s", inn2);`

Comment: tried **puts (inn2);**, works fine. next will try the other one.

Answer (score 0):

```
char test_string[] = "Hello kitty!!!\n";
printf("%.3s", test_string);
```

will print only the three first characters (or less for a shorter string) of string `test_string`.  If you don't know *a priory* the number of chars you need to print:

```
printf("%.*s", number_of_char, test_string);
```

will do the work.